# Biber with printglossaries Texmaker

Tags: glossaries, biber, texmaker

I'm trying to compile my document with Biber and the glossary in Texmaker. However, my glossary never compiles.

I edited `Bib(la)tex` so that it points to Biber's location in Texlive.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[acronym, automake]{glossaries}
\input{glossary-entries}
\usepackage{framed}

\makeglossaries

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\makeindex


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}



\chapterfont{\centering}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{3}



\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{Chapter 1}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagebreak


\section{Section 1.1}

\section{Section 1.2}

\acrlong{SoC}

\section{Section 1.3}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 2.1}

A \gls{test}

\section{Section 2.2}

\section{Section 2.3}


\subsection{subsection 2.3.1}

\subsection{subsection 2.3.2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

\printbibliography

\printglossary
\printglossary[type =\acronymtype]

\listoffigures



\end{document}
```

The glossary file is not required but here it is:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Thischapter}

\newglossaryentry{test}{
name = test,
description ={test}
}

\newacronym{SoC}{SoC}{SoC}
```

I can get my bibliography with `"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|"path_to_biber/biber" %.bcf|"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|open %.pdf` (`PdfLatex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLatex (x2) + View PDF`). However, if I try to run these 5 commands one by one I run into warnings. Why? Those warnings are not required since it compiles if I directly run the command as a Quick Build but here they are:

PdfLatex:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \underbar has changed.
LaTeX Warning: Command \underline has changed.
Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
```

Bib(la)tex: works

PdfLatex (x2): same errors as above.

I would like to know which user command I should create in user commands to compile bibliography and glossary in my document. I would like the acryonyms to appear on the page where the glossary appears. How can I make them appear in the table of contents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should either show the content of the glossary-entries.tex, or better copy the entries in your document, then no external file is needed.

Comment: I need the glossary entries as the compilation would error without it (and I wouldn't get a list of acronyms and a glossaries). With the entries it compiles fine, glossaries makes the makeindex automatically and both a glossary and a acronym is created.  biber is irrelevant for glossaries.

Comment: I asked for a command to compile everything at once. I don't think everything would be required for that. I need both the bibliography and the glossary to compile. At the moment, I only get acronyms. If I remove the acronym part of ``\usepackage[acronym, automake]{glossaries}``, nothing prints at all.

Comment: well as I said: it should work automatically. Compile twice with pdflatex and then show your log-file.

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: Yes. My manual biber command hadn't been updated and pointed to the wrong file. When I clicked on it for the manual compilation, it didn't work. When I chosed the premade biber command, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the MWE I put together will answer your three questions.

In my system (TeXstudio)  the code runs several times automatically until it finish. (`pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode   -shell-escape %.tex`)

Otherwise after a couple of compiles you should run `biber`, and compile again twice.

`makeindex` runs on every build. But if the glossay did not appear run `makeindex` and compile again.

The  `LaTeX Warning: Command \underbar  has changed. Check if current package is valid.` is coming from `sectsty.sty`. Don't worry unless you want use `sectsty` for underlining section titles.

Add `\usepackage{csquotes}` to the preamble. Loading `csquotes` is recommended when using `babel` or `polyglossia` together `biblatex`, so quoted texts are typeset using to the rules of the  main language.

[image: t]

[image: c3]

[image: b]

[image: z]

Try this code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}  % LaTeX Warning: Command \underbar  has changed.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage[acronym, automake,toc, section=section]{glossaries} % show as section

\newglossaryentry{test}{%
    name = {random test},
    description ={a random test done by a nonexpert user}
}

\newacronym{SoC}{SoC}{System on a Chip}

\makeglossaries
\glstoctrue % put Glossary and Acronyms in TOC

\usepackage{csquotes} % for biblatex <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}  % using .bib included in the distribution

\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

%\usepackage{imakeidx}% Required to make an index
%\makeindex % Create the files required for indexing 

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}   
    
    \chapterfont{\centering}    
    \pagebreak
    \setcounter{page}{3}    
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}  
    \pagebreak  
    
    \section{Section 1.1}
    
    \section{Section 1.2}
    
    \acrlong{SoC}
    
    \section{Section 1.3}
    
    \chapter{Chapter 2} 
    \section{Section 2.1}   
    \section{Section 2.2}   
    \section{Section 2.3}       
    \subsection{subsection 2.3.1}   
    \subsection{subsection 2.3.2}
    
    \chapter{Chapter 3}
    
    Doing a \gls{test} on a \acrlong{SoC} might be inconclusive and might breaks everything. See \autocite{companion}.
    
    \printbibliography  
    
    \chapter{All together}
    \printglossary
    \printglossary[type =\acronymtype]

    \listoffigures  
    
\end{document}
```